# Add linebreaks in Google forms grids & title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm currently using the following Google script to add line breaks in **questions**:

```
function addLineBreaks() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 

  var multiplechoices = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  var date = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.DATE);
  var textbox = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.TEXT);
  var checkboxgrid = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID)
  questions = multiplechoices.concat(date, textbox, checkboxgrid);

  for(i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var title = questions[i].getTitle();
    if(title.indexOf("\n") < 0) {
      questions[i].setTitle(title.replace(" | ", "\n"));
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot add line breaks to grid rows and general titles (Tt). I'm confident that it's because the script I'm using refers to `getTitle`, but couldn't get it to work with `getRows` or `setRows`.

I don't mind having to add "|" and have it replaced later with a line break when the script runs, but I do need to find a solution regarding the grids (multiple choice grids rows only).